# Append CssClass to GridViewRow with Skin when databinding

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've just created this extension:

```
public static class GridViewRowExtension
{
    public static void AppendCssClass(this GridViewRow row, string cssClass)
    {
        row.CssClass = string.Format("{0} {1}", row.CssClass, cssClass).Trim();
    }
}
```

and used it in **OnRowDataBound** event:

```
    protected void OnInstrumentsRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            AdjustRow(e.Row);
            ToggleCloseButton(e.Row);
            DisplayPerformance(e.Row);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.AppendCssClass("nodrag nodrop grt_gridview_default_header");
        }
    }
```

However appending does not work, as row.CssClass used as {0} in this line:

```
row.CssClass = string.Format("{0} {1}", row.CssClass, cssClass).Trim();
```

is empty. I was expecting that it will have a CssClass defined in GridView default skin.

I'm sure my Skin works as when I remove AppendCssClass call I see CssClass defined in skin.

Any ideas why I don't achieve what I want?

Comment: @dragonfly: are you appending this to the headerrow?

Comment: In this particular example, to footer. But I have other usages, when I need to change CssClass on random rows, based on application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try out jQuery for this, it might work for you as you want

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {$("#divGridView table tbody tr").each(function () 
     {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(this).removeClass(myClass);
    $(this).addClass(myClass + " nodrag nodrop grt_gridview_default_header");

})});
```

Comment: Thanks, although it doesn't work for me: I have other usages, when I need to change CssClass on random rows, based on application logic.